# Webpack Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, react-hooks, ts-loader

I am trying to make one React Component Package but i am getting this error after i create bundle file with webpack. I am trying to make one Component with Typescript. I didn't create project from CRA. React and React-Dom package is lastest version. when i delete the ts-loader line from webpack it is working well but decleration packages are not generating.

```
react.development.js:1634 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useEffect')
    at Object.useEffect (react.development.js:1634:1)
    at l (index.js:1:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at recoverFromConcurrentError (react-dom.development.js:25850:1)
```

My Webpack File

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.tsx"),
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    extensionAlias: {
      ".js": [".js", ".ts"],
      ".cjs": [".cjs", ".cts"],
      ".mjs": [".mjs", ".mts"]
     },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
          },
        ],
      },
      { test: /\.([cm]?ts|tsx)$/, loader: "ts-loader" },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
        type: "asset/inline",
      },
    ],
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist"),
    filename: "index.js",
    libraryTarget: "commonjs",
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.html"),
    }),
  ],
  stats: "errors-only",
};
```

Package.json file content

```
    {
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack serve --config webpack.config.js --open",
    "build": "rm -rf ./dist && webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.12",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.19.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.2",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.18.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.10",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

TS Config content is;

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES5" /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */,
      "module": "ESNext" /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */,
      "moduleResolution": "node" /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */ /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */,
     "declaration": true,
     "outDir": "dist",
      "lib": [
        "DOM",
        "ESNext"
      ] /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */,
      "jsx": "react-jsx" /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', 'react' or 'react-jsx'. */,
      "noEmit": false /* Do not emit outputs. */,
      "isolatedModules": true /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */,
      "esModuleInterop": true /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */,
      "strict": true /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */,
      "skipLibCheck": true /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      // "allowJs": true /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. Useful when migrating JS to TS */,
      // "checkJs": true /* Report errors in .js files. Works in tandem with allowJs. */,
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
  }
```

Comment: Any solution to this issue?